# angular render table ngFor for nested json with dynamic column names

Tags: json, angular

Still learning Angular (version 8). I have the following JSON

```
{layer1 : [
     {
        id: 'lay1',
        name: 'first layer',
        results:
        [
           { rows: [{ col1: '0', description: 'any'}, {col1: '0b', description: 'meh'}] },
           { rows: [{ col1: '1', description: 'some'}] },
        ]
     }
  ]
, layer2: [
     {
        id: 'lay2',
        name: 'second layer'
        results:
        [
           { rows: [{ col1: '7', description: 'more'}] },
           { rows: [{ col1: '8', description: 'none'}] },
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

The result should be a table like this

```
 <table id='lay1'>
   <tr>
     <td>0 </td>
     <td>any</td>
   </td>
   <tr>
     <td>0b </td>
     <td>meh</td>
   </td>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>some</td>
   </td>
 </table>
 <table id='lay2'>
   <tr>
     <td>7 </td>
     <td>more</td>
   </td>
   <tr>
     <td>8</td>
     <td>none</td>
   </td>
 </table>
```

note: results rows columns can change (sometimes 2 columns, sometimes 4 columns) and change the names (could be 'col1' but could be 'ident' or any other name). I have tried several options but I'm stuck on this. Any help highly appreciated

Comment: nested ngfor didn't work ? can you make a snippet ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
<table *ngFor='let tableItem of data | keyvalue' [id]='tableItem?.value[0]?.id'>
  <tbody *ngFor='let rowsItem of tableItem?.value[0]?.results; let rowIndex = index'>
    <tr *ngFor='let rowItem of rowsItem?.rows; let rowIndex = index'>
      <td *ngFor='let colItem of rowItem | keyvalue; let colIndex = index'>
        {{colItem?.value}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vnnqwi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: that worked like a charm. I made some little adjustments, since my tables are inside tabs. Thanks a lot!